# Is there a way to append from user input in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, append

Is there a way I could implement user input to create a new entry in this class I defined?

```
class Pulsar:
   'Collective base of all Pulsars'
   pulsarCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, distance):
      self.name = name
      self.distance = distance
      Pulsar.pulsarCount += 1

   def displayCount(self):
     print( "Total Pulsars %d" % Pulsar.pulsarCount)

   def displayPulsar(self):
      print( "Name : ", self.name,  ", Distance: ", self.distance)

"This creates the first object"
pulsar1 = Pulsar("B1944+17", "979 Lightyears")
"This creates the second pulsar in the class"
pulsar2 = Pulsar("J2129-5721", "1305 Lightyears")
pulsar1.displayPulsar()
pulsar2.displayPulsar()
print( "Total Pulsars %d" % Pulsar.pulsarCount)
```

I'm hoping for the user to be able to input their own name/distance and have it append to my current defined variables.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a variable that gets input() then pass that in

Comment: You should create a list of `Pulsar` instances—not store each one in a named variable. Addition instances can be created by using the `list.append()` method.

Comment: So you want to create (use) a database...?

Comment: Hi Roger, I'm a bit new with classes so I'm unsure about how to work around them. Would the input() variable be gathered outside of the class and then taken in, and would it work over multiple iterations of the program being run?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Im not sure how much more code this project has but one quick and dirty way to accomplish it would be 
pulsar1 = Pulsar(input("Name: "), input("Distance: "))
Though the list approach would be more sensible

Comment: Martineau, that sounds like the best plan. Would that be something like: self.pulsar_list = [ ] and append it that way? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Roger, I tried the way that you had suggested but unfortunately it doesn't work how I'm hoping for it to work.
Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Do Pulsar objects contain only a name and a distance? A class might be overkill for this.

Comment: @NolanCarlson-Stevermer Did you ever figure things out?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're doing with the Pulsar objects, a class may be overkill.

```py
class Pulsar:
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Pulsar({self.name!r}, {self.distance!r})'

    def __init__(self, distance: str, name: str) -> None:
        self.name: str = name
        self.distance: str = distance


num_pulsars_input = int(input('How many pulsars do you wish to create: '))

pulsar_list = []

for _ in range(num_pulsars_input):
    curr_p_name = input('Enter pulsar name: ')
    curr_p_dist = input('Enter pulsar distance: ')
    curr_p = Pulsar(curr_p_name, curr_p_dist)
    pulsar_list.append(curr_p)

print(pulsar_list)
```

Comment: `for i in pulsar_list: print(i)`

Comment: @noobninja Pardon?

Comment: `pulsar_list` returns `[<__main__.Pulsar object at 0x7f6b91e500b8>, <__main__.Pulsar object at 0x7f6b91e50048>]`

Comment: @noobninja Oh I messed something up... 2 seconds

Comment: I had added two pulsars to test multiple adds.

Comment: @noobninja Ah damn it’s because printing a container uses the `__repr__` of the contents. I’ll fix it. Thanks for checking that, I can’t believe I didn’t test it myself D:

Comment: @noobninja That should work, I tested it this time ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Pulsar:
   'Collective base of all Pulsars'
   pulsarCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, distance):
      self.name = name
      self.distance = distance
      Pulsar.pulsarCount += 1

   def displayCount(self):
     print( "Total Pulsars %d" % Pulsar.pulsarCount)

   def displayPulsar(self):
      print( "Name : ", self.name,  ", Distance: ", self.distance)

"This creates the first object"
pulsar1 = Pulsar("B1944+17", "979 Lightyears")
"This creates the second pulsar in the class"
pulsar2 = Pulsar("J2129-5721", "1305 Lightyears")
pulsar1.displayPulsar()
pulsar2.displayPulsar()
print( "Total Pulsars %d" % Pulsar.pulsarCount)

# New code
users_name = input('Your name: ')
distance = input('The distance: ')
pulsar1.name = users_name
pulsar1.distance = distance
# Then you can wrap this in a function if you want
```